# Can't click on other tabs in html tabcontent

Tags: javascript, html, css

Whenever I am on my new profile tab I can't click on my other tabs to go to them. I've included my code below. I can go from my Dashboard tab to New Profile tab fine but not the other way around. I can also go from New Task to New Profile just fine the only exception is when I go out from New Profile to another tab.

```js
document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();

function openCity(evt, cityName) {
  // Declare all variables
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;

  // Get all elements with class="tabcontent" and hide them
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }

  // Get all elements with class="tablinks" and remove the class "active"
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }

  // Show the current tab, and add an "active" class to the button that opened the tab
  document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
  console.log("hello");
}
```

```css
label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 140px;
  text-align: right;
}

input {
  width: 140px
}

select {
  width: 140px;
}


/* Split the screen in half */

.split {
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  padding-top: 20px;
}


/* If you want the content centered horizontally and vertically */

.centered {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
}


/* Control the left side */

.left {
  left: 0;
  /*background-color: #111; */
}


/* Control the right side */

.right {
  right: 0;
  /*background-color: red; */
}


/* Style the tab */

.tab {
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  position: relative;
  clear: both;
}


/* Style the buttons that are used to open the tab content */

.tab button {
  background-color: inherit;
  float: left;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  transition: 0.3s;
}


/* Change background color of buttons on hover */

.tab button:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}


/* Create an active/current tablink class */

.tab button.active {
  background-color: #ccc;
}


/* Style the tab content */

.tabcontent {
  display: none;
  padding: 1280px 720px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-top: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Document</title>


</head>

<body>
  <!-- For the tab headers-->
  <div class="tab">
    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'ProfileTab')">New Profile</button>
    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'TaskTab')" id="defaultOpen">New Task</button>
    <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'DashboardTab')">Dashboard</button>
  </div>


  <div id="ProfileTab" class="tabcontent">
    <!-- Shipping and billing details will be on left half of screen. -->
    <div class="split left">
      <!-- Shipping Details -->
      <h1>Shipping Details</h1>
      <div class="block">
        <label for="firstNameTextFieldShip">First Name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="firstNameTextFieldShip" name="firstNameShip">


        <label for="lastNameTextFieldShip">Last Name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="lastNameTextFieldShip" name="lastNameShip">
      </div>

      <br>

      <div class="block">
        <label for="Address1TextFieldShip">Address:</label>
        <input type="text" id="Address1TextFieldShip" name="add1txtfieldShip">

        <label for="Address2TextField">Address 2:</label>
        <input type="text" id="Address2TextFieldShip" name="add2txtfieldShip">
      </div>

      <br>

      <div class="block">
        <label for="ZipTextFieldShip">Zip Code:</label>
        <input type="text" id="ZipTextFieldShip" name="ziptxtfieldShip">

        <label for="CityTextFieldShip">City:</label>
        <input type="text" id="CityTextFieldShip" name="citytxtfieldShip">
      </div>

      <br>

      <div class="block">
        <label for="CountriesSelectShip">Country:</label>
        <select id="CountriesSelectShip">
          <option value="USA">USA</option>
        </select>

        <label for="StateTextFieldShip">State:</label>
        <input type="text" id="StateTextFieldShip" name="statetxtfieldShip">
      </div>



      <!-- Billing Details-->
      <h1>Billing Details</h1>
      <div class="block">
        <label for="firstNameTextFieldBilling">First Name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="firstNameTextFieldBilling" name="firstNameBilling">


        <label for="lastNameTextFieldBilling">Last Name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="lastNameTextFieldBilling" name="lastNameBilling">
      </div>

      <br>

      <div class="block">
        <label for="Address1TextFieldBilling">Address:</label>
        <input type="text" id="Address1TextFieldBilling" name="add1txtfieldBilling">

        <label for="Address2TextFieldBilling">Address 2:</label>
        <input type="text" id="Address2TextFieldBilling" name="add2txtfieldBilling">
      </div>

      <br>

      <div class="block">
        <label for="ZipTextFieldBilling">Zip Code:</label>
        <input type="text" id="ZipTextFieldBilling" name="ziptxtfieldBilling">

        <label for="CityTextFieldBilling">City:</label>
        <input type="text" id="CityTextFieldBilling" name="citytxtfieldBilling">
      </div>

      <br>

      <div class="block">
        <label for="CountriesSelectBilling">Country:</label>
        <select id="CountriesSelectBilling">
          <option value="USA">USA</option>
        </select>

        <label for="StateTextFieldBilling">State:</label>
        <input type="text" id="StateTextFieldBilling" name="statetxtfieldBilling">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="split right">

      <h1>Payment Information</h1>
      <div class="block">
        <label for="ProfileNameTextField">Profile Name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="ProfileNameTextField" name="profileNameTextField">
      </div>

      <br>

      <div class="block">
        <label for="EmailTextField">Email:</label>
        <input type="text" id="EmailTextField" name="emailTextField">
      </div>

      <br>

      <div class="block">
        <label for="PhoneNumTextField">Phone Number:</label>
        <input type="text" id="PhoneNumTextField" name="PhoneNumTextField">
      </div>

      <br>

      <div class="block">
        <label for="NameOnCardTextField">Name On Card:</label>
        <input type="text" id="NameOnCardTextField" name="NameOnCardTextField">
      </div>

      <br>

      <div class="block">
        <label for="NumOnCardTextField">Number On Card:</label>
        <input type="text" id="NumOnCardTextField" name="NumOnCardTextField">
      </div>

      <br>

      <div class="block">
        <label for="ExpirationTextField">Expiration Date:</label>
        <input type="text" id="ExpirationTextField" name="ExpirationTextField">
      </div>

      <br>

      <div class="block">
        <label for="CVVTextField">CVV:</label>
        <input type="text" id="CVVTextField" name="CVVTextField">
      </div>

      <br>
    </div>

  </div>

  <!-- Tasks tab -->
  <div id="TaskTab" class="tabcontent">
    <h1>hi</h1>
  </div>

  <!-- Dashboard tab -->
  <div id="DashboardTab" class="tabcontent">

  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

[Can't click on dashboard or New Task tab after being on New Profile tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LIE9E.png)

Answer (score 0):

Your Tabs are working as expected. Your container "div id="ProfileTab" class="tabcontent" style="display: block;" is sitting over top of the tabs making it so you can't click them. You just need to fix the positioning of that container so it is not blocking the tabs

Answer (score 0):

Quick answer: remove the padding on `.tabcontent` and remove the position on `.split`. Then add `float: left;` to `.split`.

The overall issue is the content of the `tabcontent` was out of document flow causing it to overlap the tabs in the DOM. So, even though it looked like you were clicking the tab, you were actually clicking the `tabcontent`

The float is a quick fix for displaying things side by side and not really "wrong". The preference now days is to use flexbox. I would recommend looking it up. Here is a guide and a fun game:
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

https://flexboxfroggy.com/